# System design : how to make sure two DB receive the same data (synchronous)?

Tags: oracle, synchronization, data-synchronization, system-design

I have an API 1 which should call API 2 and API 3 at the same time to update each of their database DB1 and DB2.

Now I face a problem, I want to make sure that the two DB are synchronized. That's to say, if DB1 does not receive the message and DB2 does, there should be a rollback in DB2 side (and vice versa).

Is there a system pattern to solve this kind of synchro problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like bad design or more info needed. API2 and API3 are different or exactly same code for redundancy? If they are equal I would use database features to make sure you have 2 copies in sync and wouldn't move that into application. Take a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION

Comment: hi, in fact DB1 is a blackbox (something like HBase) and DB2 is oracle, we have to do the check in application side

Comment: If Hbase role is a cache I would just write to RDBMS first, then write to HBase and on read I would fallback to RDBMS if cache entry is missing. Distributed transactions is a tricky stuff.

Comment: the problem is that the client wants the change quick, so we have to write it in cache first. And if we write to oracle from the cache it would be too slow

Comment: so we decided to write to two database at the same time, I don't know if there's a better option....

Comment: https://codeahoy.com/2017/08/11/caching-strategies-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/

Comment: "The client wants".  Sometimes what the client wants goes against the laws of physics. Sometimes what the client wants is world peace.  Sometimes the client has to be educated that the difference between what he perceives that he wants and what you can actually deliver makes no business difference at all, that it is just a differenct technique of getting there.